# SQL Server / T-SQL : query optimization assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I have this QA logic that looks for errors into every `AuditID` within a `RoomID` to see if their `AuditType` were never marked Complete or if they have two complete statuses. Finally, it picks only the maximum `AuditDate` of the `RoomID`s with errors to avoid showing multiple instances of the same `RoomID`, since there are many audits per room.

The issue is that the AUDIT table is very large and takes a long time to run. I was wondering if there is anyway to reach the same result faster.

Thank you in advance !

```
IF object_ID('tempdb..#AUDIT') is not null  drop table #AUDIT
IF object_ID('tempdb..#ROOMS') is not null  drop table #ROOMS
IF object_ID('tempdb..#COMPLETE') is not null  drop table #COMPLETE
IF object_ID('tempdb..#FINALE') is not null  drop table #FINALE

SELECT distinct 
    oc.HotelID, o.RoomID
INTO #ROOMS
FROM  dbo.[rooms] o
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[hotels] oc on o.HotelID = oc.HotelID
WHERE 
    o.[status] = '2' 
    AND o.orderType = '2' 

SELECT 
    t.AuditID, t.RoomID, t.AuditDate, t.AuditType
INTO  
    #AUDIT
FROM 
    [dbo].[AUDIT] t
WHERE
    t.RoomID IN (SELECT RoomID FROM #ROOMS) 


SELECT 
    t1.RoomID, t3.AuditType, t3.AuditDate, t3.AuditID, t1.CompleteStatus
INTO 
    #COMPLETE
FROM
    (SELECT 
         RoomID,
         SUM(CASE WHEN AuditType = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CompleteStatus
     FROM 
         #AUDIT
     GROUP BY 
         RoomID) t1
INNER JOIN
    #AUDIT t3 ON t1.RoomID = t3.RoomID
WHERE 
    t1.CompleteStatus = 0
    OR t1.CompleteStatus > 1


SELECT 
    o.HotelID, o.RoomID, 
    a.AuditID, a.RoomID, a.AuditDate, a.AuditType, a.CompleteStatus,
    c.ClientNum
INTO
    #FINALE
FROM 
    #ROOMS O
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    #COMPLETE a on o.RoomID = a.RoomID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[clients] c on o.clientNum = c.clientNum


SELECT
    t.*,
    Complete_Error_Status = CASE WHEN t.CompleteStatus = 0 
                                    THEN 'Not Complete'
                                 WHEN t.CompleteStatus > 1 
                                    THEN 'Complete More Than Once' 
                            END
FROM
    #FINALE t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         RoomID, MAX(AuditDate) AS MaxDate
     FROM
         #FINALE
     GROUP BY 
         RoomID) tm ON t.RoomID = tm.RoomID AND t.AuditDate = tm.MaxDate
```

Comment: Why this `SUM(CASE WHEN AuditType = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` when you can simply filter the data set by `WHERE AuditType = 'Complete'`?

Comment: @Nicarus My thought process is that I am looking at all the instances where AuditType = 'complete' within a roomID . by all means if you know a better way .. I am here to learn..

Comment: Consider indexing your temp tables. WHERE EXISTS is often (but not always) faster than IN.  OR is slow, replace with a UNION  ALL when you can.

Comment: @H.Ben - My point is that you are not limiting the set of data, yet you are only summing a limited set of the data. It is unnecessary.

Comment: which version of sql-server are you using 2012 or later?  reading through this query you can probably dump/not use a lot of the temp tables restrict your results on joins more effectively and use MAX() OVER window function and it should perform a lot better but ultimately what is indexed and what is not and a few other things will be key too

Comment: By no means is this a performance problem but it did make me chuckle. "t1.CompleteStatus = 0
    OR t1.CompleteStatus > 1" You could make that a bit simple with "t1.CompleteStatus >= 0". :D

Comment: @SeanLange because t1.CompleteStatus > 0 would include the #1 and he is saying that isn't an error by his code.  I have to admit it took me a minute and a double take as well though!

Comment: Ahh yeah....still kind of funny but you are correct.

Comment: @ Sean Lange = 1 is the only instance where it would not be an error. you made me think about that for a bit there lol .

Comment: I think @Nicarus Makes a good Point.

Comment: I tried it your way @Nicarus but I am not getting any results (I know there should be results). Maybe if you could show us concretely what you meant it would be more constructive. I think you are the closest to solving this question. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: `SELECT RoomID, SUM(CASE WHEN AuditType = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CompleteStatus FROM #AUDIT GROUP BY RoomID` should produce the same results as `SELECT RoomID, COUNT(1) AS CompleteStatus FROM #AUDIT WHERE AuditType = 'Complete' GROUP BY RoomID`

Comment: @Nicarus How do you determine which one has either not had an audit completed or completed more than once. (which are the errors we want to raise)? also you may want to post an answer instead of a comment so I can give you the check mark.

Comment: Since nobody else seems to ask for it, what indexes are there on the tables involved? (hotels, audits, rooms) [`sp_helpindex` output for those three would be really helpful]. Also, could you give an idea about the volumes ('a lot' and 'big' is way to subjective =), the amount of records each of your temptables gets and how long each step takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One section you could improve would be this one. See the inline comments.

```
SELECT 
    t1.RoomID, t3.AuditType, t3.AuditDate, t3.AuditID, t1.CompleteStatus
INTO 
    #COMPLETE
FROM
    (SELECT 
         RoomID,
         COUNT(1) AS CompleteStatus
         -- Use the above along with the WHERE clause below
         -- so that you are aggregating fewer records and
         -- avoiding a CASE statement. Remove this next line.
         --SUM(CASE WHEN AuditType = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CompleteStatus
     FROM 
         #AUDIT
     WHERE
         AuditType = 'Complete'
     GROUP BY 
         RoomID) t1
INNER JOIN
    #AUDIT t3 ON t1.RoomID = t3.RoomID
WHERE
    t1.CompleteStatus = 0
    OR t1.CompleteStatus > 1
```

Comment: I am trying this now, the last part is wrong and has been discussed =0 or >1 is not equal to >=0 the later includes 1 whilst 1 is the only instance where an error should not be raised.

Comment: Sorry @Nicarus it's slower .. like I previously said <pre> <code> the audit table is the problem : SELECT 
    t.AuditID, t.RoomID, t.AuditDate, t.AuditType
INTO  
    #AUDIT
FROM 
    [dbo].[AUDIT] t
WHERE
    t.RoomID IN (SELECT RoomID FROM #ROOMS)

Comment: How are you testing? Are you using the query planner/analyzer?

Comment: Also, do you have an index on `AuditType`?

Comment: I am converting it to my actual query and executing it on SQL server 2012 , I am not using planner/analyzer, there is a non clustered index on `AuditType`

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  Streamline your code and your solution.  you are not effectively filtering your datasets smaller so you continue to query the entire tables which is taking a lot of your resources and your temp tables are becoming full copies of those columns without the indexes (PK, FK, ++??) on the original table to take advantage of.  This by no means is a perfect solution but it is an idea of how you can consolidate your logic and reduce your overall data set.  Give it a try and see if it performs better for you.

Note this will return the last audit record for any room that has either not had an audit completed or completed more than once.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       o.RoomId
       ,o.clientNum
       ,a.AuditId
       ,a.AuditDate
       ,a.AuditType
       ,NumOfAuditsComplete = SUM(CASE WHEN a.AuditType = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY o.RoomId)
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.RoomId ORDER BY a.AuditDate DESC)
    FROm
       dbo.Rooms o
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Audit a
       ON o.RoomId = a.RoomId
WHERE
   o.[Status] = 2
   AND o.OrderType = 2
)

SELECT
    oc.HotelId
    ,cte.RoomId
    ,cte.AuditId
    ,cte.AuditDate
    ,cte.AuditType
    ,cte.NumOfAuditsComplete
    ,cte.clientNum
    ,Complete_Error_Status = CASE WHEN cte.NumOfAuditsComplete > 1 THEN 'Complete More Than Once' ELSE 'Not Complete' END
FROM
    cte
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Hotels oc
    ON cte.HotelId = oc.HotelId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.clients c
    ON cte.clientNum = c.clientNum
WHERE
    cte.RowNum = 1
    AND cte.NumOfAuditsComplete != 1
```

Also note I changed your

```
WHERE 
    o.[status] = '2' 
    AND o.orderType = '2'
```

TO

```
WHERE 
    o.[status] = 2 
    AND o.orderType = 2
```

to be numeric without the single quotes.  If the data type is truely varchar add them back but when you query a numeric column as a varchar it will do data conversion and may not take advantage of indexes that you have built on the table.

Comment: this seems to be slower .. sorry

Comment: sometimes ctes can be as the sql engine doesn't always optimize them correctly.  I would guess that you could probably use an index on audit that will include AuditType.  If you post your execution plan to your query and I would love to see that of this one too I am sure people will be able to give you more specific advice.  in case you are not aware of how, to get it right click in the query window and choose "include actual execution plan" it will give you another tab next to results and messages

Comment: also if you click display estimated execute plan it will usually give you suggested missing indexes which is likely something you will need.

Comment: thnak you for your comments @Matt like I said it is really that the AUDIT table is huge and it takes forever to search every audit within every room.

Comment: yeah I get it, I have a transactional property management system for 7 hotels that I query..  Building indexes will take up more space but could make it a lot faster.  So if you build an index on Audit that takes into account AuditType then you can generate a temp table with roomid as a primary key (which is an index) to work with, but when you go back to get the last row you will still have a row_number operation that will again hit that large table to find it.